# Filter conditions don't get preserved when moving to next page of the result

Tags: support, bug, search-box

I have the following custom filter:

[image: sample custom filter]

Sometimes if I also want to mark `No answers` and **Apply filter**, this setting is preserved only for the first page of the result; when I click the next page, then the result includes posts with answers, so the Filter by `No Answers` is not longer applied.

Comment: I can confirm this. A workaround is saving that filter with a custom name, then that's applied to all the pages.

Comment: Thanks, @MagnusO_O so it seems to be a bug in the search engine.